# Один Edit для двух связанных моделей

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть модели

```
public class Pole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public virtual Purchase Purchase { get; set; }
    public int PurchaseId { get; set; }

}
public class Purchase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public string Post { get; set; }
    public int DealSum { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Pole> Poles { get; set; }
    public Purchase()
    {
    Poles = new List<Pole>();
    }

}
```

Контроллер PurchaseController

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Purchase purchase = db.Purchases.Find(id);
        if (purchase == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(purchase);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Phone,Mail,Post,DealSum,Status")] Purchase purchase)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(purchase).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(purchase);
    }
```

Представление
         @model Business.Models.Purchase

```
     @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
      }

     <h2>Edit</h2>
     @{
     List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
     list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "В процессе" });

     list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Завершено" });
      }

     @using (Html.BeginForm())
     {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Purchase</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Post, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Post, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DealSum, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DealSum, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DealSum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, list)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default"                                  name="Value"/> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

   }


   <div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
   </div>

  @section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  }
```

То есть у каждого объекта Purchase есть связанные с ним объекты Pole.
Можно редактировать оба объекта с помощью разных представлений.
Вопрос таков:как с помощью одного представления редактировать обе модели(то есть сам Purchase и связанные с ним Pole)? 
Пытался осуществить это добавлением куска кода в предыдущее представление

```
 @foreach(var i in Model.Poles)
 {
     @Html.EditorFor(modelI => i.Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class     = "form-control" } })
 }
```

Comment: MVC? Что есть "Editы для ... моделей"? Controller Action? View? NB: у Вас не стоит задача сформулировать вопрос, используя минимум слов.

Comment: Controller и View

Comment: Будьте добры, добавьте в вопрос описание того, что Вы пытались сделать, указав также, что именно не получилось.

Comment: @Igor вроде пояснил)

Comment: удалите [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/463714/edit-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8) дубликат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class Pole
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public int PurchaseId { get; set; }

    }

public class Purchase{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Mail { get; set; }
        public string Post { get; set; }
        public int DealSum { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
public class PurchaseModel{
            public Purchase Purchase{ get; set; }
            public Pole Pole { get; set; }
        }
```

Ты можешь определить модель PurchaseModel для вьюшки:

```
@model PurchaseModel
```

далее можно обращаться данным Pole и Purchase:

```
Model.Pole.Name
Model.Purchase.Name
```

но чтобы не приходили пустые данные надо заполнить и передать во вьюшку модель PurchaseModel в методе [HttpGet] Edit:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var purchase = db.Purchases.Find(id);
    if (purchase == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    var purchaseModel = new PurchaseModel(){
          Purchase = new Purchase(){
          Name = "PoleName",
          //......
        },
       Pole = new Pole(){
        Name = "PoleName",
        //......
       }
    }
    return View(purchaseModel);
}
```

и ты в пост будет приходит модель PurchaseModel, в посте надо брать нужные данные и отдельно Purchase и Pole сохранять:

```
    [HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(PurchaseModel purchaseModel)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var purchase = new Purchase(){Name=purchaseModel.Purchase.Name,//...}
        db.Entry(purchase).State = EntityState.Modified;

        var pole= new Pole(){Name=purchaseModel.Pole.Name,//...}
        db.Entry(pole).State = EntityState.Modified;

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(purchaseModel);
}
```